# WordPress, hardcoding page but want relative links to image

Tags: php, wordpress

I paid a guy to build a website for me, http://www.brilliantzenaudio.com, but I ran out of money so I'm trying to learn how to make some modifications myself.

I'm "hardcoding" front-page.php rather than using the control panel editor. I want to link to some images and I want to use relative links if possible. If I put an image in `themes/brilliantzen/assets/img/` how do I write the link to that in the  tag? Or on the other hand, if I put an image in the library how do I refer to it with php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the path to your root:

```
<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>
```

This will give you the path to your theme directory:

```
<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>
```

This will also give you the path to theme:

```
<?php get_template_directory(); ?>
```

Here is an example of how I have done it:

```
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/example.png" />
```

Here are the docs on this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Comment: I don't know that much about PHP, but how would that look in the img tag? something like `<img src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/whatever.jpg">` ???

Comment: I added an example from what I usually do.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful you can select it as the correct answer.